# Recibir el valor de una columna

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablaParticiones.getModel();
    int[] rows = tablaParticiones.getSelectedRows();
    for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        int disponible = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        int actualAfterDelete = disponible + rows[i][1].getText();
        jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(actualAfterDelete));
        model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
    }
}
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es sumar el valor almacenado al valor disponible en la segunda columna de la fila `i`.

Pero al querer hacerlo de esta manera me aparece el error:

> array required, but int found

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

Comment: Si `rows` está definido así: `int[] rows`, no puedes hacer esto: `rows[i][1]` porque `rows` solo tiene una dimensión.

Comment: Si eso note, ya encontré la solución

Answer (score 0):

El error se presenta al momento de querer acceder a la celda, estas tratando a rows como una array bidimensional cuando está declarado como array unidimensional. Una posible solución para acceder a la celda, es que utilices el método `getValueAt(int row, int column)` de la clase `JTable`.

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablaParticiones.getModel();
    int[] rows = tablaParticiones.getSelectedRows();
    for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        int disponible = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        int actualAfterDelete = disponible + (int)tablaParticiones.getValueAt(rows[i],1);
        jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(actualAfterDelete));
        model.removeRow(rows[i]-i);
    }
}
```

Para más información sobre los métodos de JTable: [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)!